# SQL Server aggregate rows into column values

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

first time post on this site but I've used it a lot in the past. I did try to search for an answer to this but couldn't nail down how to frame the question properly, so here goes.

I have a table where each row has an evaluation number of 1, 2, 3 or 4. Each row also has an ID that is a foreign key to a membership table, and another ID that is a foreign key to other data related to the row (a table that holds test information).

What I need to do is filter this list of records by the membership group, and then create an output query of some type that lists:

1. The test ID
2. The number of records that are evaluated to 1
3. The number of records that are evaluated to 2
4. The number of records that are evaluated to 3
5. The number of records that are evaluated to 4

I can work out how to get the count of each evaluation number separately using something like:

```
SELECT Count(Eval), scores.TestID
FROM membership INNER JOIN (scores INNER JOIN tests ON scores.TestID = tests.TestID) ON membership.ID = scores.ClientID
WHERE membership.GroupID = <MembershipGroup> AND scores.Eval = 1;
```

Where in the above  is the main filter, scores.TestID is the 'grouping' ID, and Count(Eval) is the aggregate I want. Essentially my ideal output is:

```
ID   |Count1|Count2|Count3|Count4
-----------------------------------
100  |5     |8     |9     |12
101  |16    |2     |14    |11
```

...and such. Again, sorry if this was a garbled mess, hopefully you lot can help!

PS. The resultant query will be retrieved from ASP.NET to bind to a ListView - if anyone can advise on whether I am better off writing this up as a stored procedure and looking that up or coding it into the SQLDataSource in ASP that would be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `SUM`, `CASE` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT scores.TestID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Eval = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Count1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Eval = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Count2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Eval = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Count3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Eval = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Count4
FROM membership 
    INNER JOIN scores 
        ON membership.ID = scores.ClientID
    INNER JOIN tests ON scores.TestID = tests.TestID
WHERE membership.GroupID = <MembershipGroup>
GROUP BY scores.TestID
```

Comment: Wow that is amazing, and worked perfectly first time. Thank you sir, you are an actual genius!

Comment: @user2247277 -- np, glad we could help!

Answer (score 1):

On the thought that you have a pre-defined set of evaluations of 1-4, I would use case statements in conjunction with your group by.

```
SELECT s.TestId, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN m.Eval = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 ) END AS Count1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN m.Eval = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 ) END AS Count2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN m.Eval = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 ) END AS Count3,
       SUM(CASE WHEN m.Eval = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 ) END AS Count4
FROM membership m
    INNER JOIN scores s ON  m.ID = s.ClientID 
WHERE m.GroupId = <MembershipGroup>
GROUP BY s.TestId
```

As for the other aspect of the question, I personally don't use the SQLDataSource objects. Additionally, placing this in a Stored Procedure allows you to modify the query logic on an as needed basis without requiring a recompile.  That said, just because you're using a stored procedure doesn't mean that you can't use the SQLDataSource objects.

Comment: Great answer here too Stephen, thankyou. Do you DataBind() each data object in code and generate the SQL retrieval yourself? Would you recommend this over using the SqlDataSource? Or is that just your personal preference?

Comment: I databind each object in code, and generate the SQL retrieval either via SqlClient objects or LINQ classes. It's my personal preference, and I recommend it. It's been my experience that you can make the controls and underlying SQL do MORE with doing this in the code behind. Of course that experience is jaded and biased by a dislike of using the DataSource objects.